# Jmeter APDEX report values mismatch

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

I have run a load test with 200 users and using `APDEX` reporting that jmeter provides. So in this final report, I notice my total transactions count is not matching with the `KO` column. Below is a snapshot format:

```
Label        #Samples     KO
Transaction9    2383      0 
Transaction10   2383      0
Transaction11   2383      0
Transaction12   2383     27
Transaction13.  2383      0
```

Note:

In `transaction12`, I have an assertion `JSR223 Assertion` which I am setting as false when a sample with this transaction fails using `AssertionResult.setFailure(true)`. So my expectation is the report should be as follows:

```
Label        #Samples     KO
Transaction9    2383      0 
Transaction10   2383      0
Transaction11   2383      0
Transaction12   2383     27
Transaction13.  2356      0
```

I followed jmeter documentation to generate this type of report. Let me know some of your thoughts/experiences.

Comment: you expect the test to stop if sampler failed?

Comment: i dont want to stop the thread, rather i wish to proceed with next iteration

Comment: So are you saying that this count will be matched only when we handle to stop the thread?

Comment: you expect thread to stop after failing Transaction12  and not process Transaction13, no ?

Comment: What if we do that? then only the count will be matched?

Answer (score 0):

I think you expect to stop current thread to continue to next samplers if sampler failed

In that case set [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)'s `Action to be taken after a Sampler error` as `Stop Thread`

> Determines what happens if a sampler error occurs, either because the sample itself failed or an assertion failed.

Comment: Hi , I do not want to continue the loop, i want to exit the current loop and ignore the response time for this transaction which has this sample.